# Stackoverflow exception on addActionListener method

Tags: java

I have some problems with my application. I'm trying to create a JButton just with AWT components. The main problem is that I have an exception : at QButton.QButton.addActionListener(QButton.java:83).
    If i comment the line //this.addActionListener everything is ok. My object is extends Panel

```
public class QButton extends Panel implements MouseListener,ActionListener{
    public Label text;
    ImagePanel image;
    ActionListener listener;

    public QButton(String text){
        Label l = new Label(text);
        this.add(l);
        this.text=l;

        this.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        this.setBackground(Color.gray);

        TextButtonActions ac1=new TextButtonActions(this);
        this.addMouseListener(ac1);
        this.text.addMouseListener(ac1);
    }

    public QButton(ImagePanel img){
        this.setLayout(new GridLayout());

        this.image=img;        
        this.add(image);

        PictureButtonActions ac2=new PictureButtonActions(this);
        this.image.addMouseListener(ac2);
        }

    public QButton(String text, ImagePanel img){
        this.setBackground(Color.gray);
        this.setLayout(new GridLayout());

        Label l = new Label(text);
        this.add(l);
        this.text=l;

        this.image=img;
        this.add(image);

        TAndPButtonActions ac3=new TAndPButtonActions(this);
        this.image.addMouseListener(ac3);
        this.text.addMouseListener(ac3);
    }

    public void setText(String txt)
    {
        this.text.setText(txt);
    }

    public String getText()
    {
        return(text.getText());
    }

    public void setImage(ImagePanel i)
    {
        this.remove(image);
        this.image=i;

        this.add(i);
        //System.out.println("setImage");
        this.validate();
    }

    public ImagePanel getImage()
    {
        return(image);
    }

    void addActionListener(ActionListener listener)
    {
        this.listener=listener;
        this.addActionListener(listener);
    }
}
```

Comment: ah another stackoverflow problem on stackoverflow !!

Comment: What do you expect? `this.addActionListener(listener);` unconditionally calls itself

Answer (score 3):

I'm not familiar with UI things, but the reason you get a `StackOverflowException`, is because your program trying to invoke the method which will call itself.

```
void addActionListener(ActionListener listener)
   // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
{
    this.listener=listener;
    this.addActionListener(listener); // <-- will keep calling itself.
       //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
}
```

Comment: +1 - and it is worth pointing out that this should be **obvious** if the OP bothered to print / look at the exception's stacktrace.  First lesson of Java debugging ... look at the stacktrace!

Comment: so how can i create an addActionListener method for my own component? I have the same problem with an image on which i want to put a MouseListener.

Comment: @Magda Maria Magdalena > You might want to search around for the answer. If there is no one, start a new question with proper title. Explain what you want to do, what problem you have, and what did you try/expected, explain it in detail, so other people who knows about UI can help you without spending much time trying to figure what you want to do. You can read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) . Welcome to SO.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you meant to say `super.addActionListener(listener);`?